# get clicked div distance from top

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the div distance from top. I know it sounds easy but let me explain you.

I have many divs with the same class `.item` and not all of them are at same distance from top. So, when I try something like

```
var $distanceItem = $('.item').position().top;
alert($distanceItem);
```

it obviously returns the same value, even if the clicked element is further down, because they share the same class.

I'd like to know if is possible to get the distance from top of the element I click on. I must say I cannot use `id's`.

Many thanks

Comment: Where's your click handler function? How do you execute that code? You're going to need `this` or `$(this)` but without a [mcve] a useful answer will be difficult

Answer (score 2):

The clicked element is bound to `this` variable in jQuery's click event callback function, so `$(this).offset().top;` will give you its position from top. See this demo:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.item', function(e){
  var positionFromTop = $(this).offset().top;
  $('#result').html('Clicked div position from top: ' + positionFromTop + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot AVAVT, this is what I tried but it didn't work to me due to a syntax error. My bad. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there are more than 1 divs with the same class, jQuery's .position() function takes the first div with that class and returns its' position. Thats why you get the same value.

In order to get the position of the element that was CLICKED on, you can just use `this` variable in the click handler, like this:

```
// when any div that has the class="item" is clicked, call the same function 
$(".item").click(function() {
    // same function is called for every click, but the magic behind ``this`` is that
    // in the click event callback, it changes to the item that was clicked on

    var $distanceItem = $(this).position().top;
    alert($distanceItem);
});
```